# Curl thowing error while trying to query JIRA with strings in field filter

Tags: perl, curl, jira, jql

I need some help with my perl script.

I am new to perl and using curl and despite a lot of searching/ trial and error I am still stumped.

I am trying to use CURL to retrieve a set of jira issues based on the provided JQL.

Unfortunately I am having issues with spaces when I search fields like summary:

```
my $jql = JiraUrl.'search?jql=summary~"Some%20Silly%20Issue"';
```

When I curl this...

```
my $jsonResponse = `curl -D- -u $user:$password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" $jql`;
```

I get an error ..

```
{"errorMessages":["Error in the JQL Query: Expecting either \'OR\' or \'AND\' but got \'Silly\'. (line 1, character 77)"],"errors":{}}';
```

Basicly when I escape the " " with %20 it ignores the "'s

Any help for how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's a shell escaping issue.  The quotes are being interpreted by the shell.  Try this:

```
my $jsonResponse = `curl -D- -u $user:$password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" '$jql'`;
```